# javascript error - node was not found : replaceChild

Tags: javascript

I am trying to swap two array in javascript. While the replacement comes to the last iteration, I am getting "NotFoundError: Node was not found" in the call of parent.replaceChild(item2,item1). Please help me what mistake I have committed.

```
    function sortTable(col){
            if($("loacte-resultsTable") == null || $("loacte-resultsTable") == undefined){  
            return false;
        }

    if (lastSort == col) {    
        // sorting on same column twice = reverse sort order
        absOrder ? absOrder = false : absOrder = true
    }
    else{
        absOrder = true
    }   
    lastSort = col;

    try{        
        var loacteResultsTable = $("loacte-resultsTable").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
        var loacteResultsTableTR = loacteResultsTable.getElementsByTagName("TR");
        allTR = loacteResultsTableTR;
    } catch (e) {   
        return false;       
    }

    // allTR now holds all the rows in the dataTable
    totalRows = allTR.length;
    colToSort = new Array();        //holds all the cells in the column to sort
    colArr = new Array();           //holds all the rows that correspond to the sort cell
    copyArr = new Array();          //holds an original copy of the sort data  to match to colArr
    resultArr = new Array();        //holds the output

    allNums = true
    allDates = true

    //store the original data
    //remember that the first row - [0] -  has column headings
    //so start with the second row - [1]
    //and load the contents of the cell into the array that will be sorted
    for (x=0; x < totalRows; x++){
        var data = setDataType(allTR[x].childNodes[col].innerText);
        if(typeof data!="undefined"){
            colToSort[x] = setDataType(allTR[x].childNodes[col].innerText);
        }else{
            colToSort[x] = setDataType(allTR[x].childNodes[col].textContent);
        }
        colArr[x] = allTR[x];           
    }

    //make a copy of the original
    for (x=0; x<colToSort.length; x++){
        copyArr[x] = colToSort[x];
    }   
    //sort the original data based on data type
    if (allNums){
        colToSort.sort(numberOrder);
    } else if (allDates){
        colToSort.sort(dateOrder);
    } else {    
        colToSort.sort(textOrder);
    }

    //match copy to sorted
    for(x=0; x<colToSort.length; x++) { 
        for(y=0; y<copyArr.length; y++) {
            if (colToSort[x] == copyArr[y]) {
                boolListed = false
                //search the ouput array to make sure not to use duplicate rows

                for(z=0; z<resultArr.length; z++) {
                    if (resultArr[z]==y) {
                        boolListed = true
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!boolListed){
                    resultArr[x] = y
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //now display the results - it is as simple as swapping rows
    for (x=0; x<resultArr.length; x++) {    
        //allTR[x].swapNode(colArr[resultArr[x]])
        swapNodes(allTR[x],colArr[resultArr[x]]);
    }
    function swapNodes(item1,item2)
    {
        var itemtmp = item1.cloneNode(1);
        var parent = item1.parentNode;
        item2 = parent.replaceChild(itemtmp,item2);
        parent.replaceChild(item2,item1);
        parent.replaceChild(item1,itemtmp);
        itemtmp = null;
    }

}
```

The call to the sortTable method is from synch().This is the UI part coded in JS:

```
function synch(){

    var loacteResults = $('loacte-results');
    var loacteResultsTable = $('loacte-resultsTable');

    tab = loacteResults.getElementsByTagName('TABLE')[0];
    loacteResults.removeChild(tab);

    var updatedResults =
                '<table id="loacte-resultsTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1">' + 
                '<thead class="thead">' + 
                    '<tr>' + 
                        '<th>Site ID</th>' + 
                        '<th>Store Name</th>' + 
                        '<th>Agent Code</th>' + 
                        '<th>Address</th>' + 
                        '<th>City, State</th>' + 
                        '<th>Phone</th>' + 
                        '<th>Hours</th>' + 
                        '<th>Deleted</th>' + 
                        '<th width="65px;">Priority <img src="images/sort_up_down.gif" onclick="javascript:sortTable(8)" style="cursor: pointer;"/></th>' + 
                        '<th width="115px;">Est.Dist.(miles) <img src="images/sort_up_down.gif" onclick="javascript:sortTable(9)" style="cursor: pointer;"/></th>' + 
                    '</tr>' + 
                '</thead>' ;

    if(tr == '')
        updatedResults = updatedResults + '<tbody><tr><td colspan="10">No Stores to display</td></tr></tbody></table>';
    else                        
        updatedResults = updatedResults + '<tbody>' + tr +  '</tbody></table>';             

    loacteResults.innerHTML = updatedResults;

}
```

Comment: Please include a running example on codepen, jsfiddle, plunkr or alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In the third `parent.replaceChild` line `item1` is no longer is on the page, since it has been replaced with item2.

Your code broken down:

```
function swapNodes(item1,item2)
{
    var itemtmp = item1.cloneNode(1); //create a copy of item 1
    var parent = item1.parentNode; //set a reference to the parent
    item2 = parent.replaceChild(itemtmp,item2); //replace item2 with the copy of item1 and store the old child in item2
    parent.replaceChild(item2,item1); //replace item1 with item2
    parent.replaceChild(item1,itemtmp); //this line is redundant. <-- item1 no longer is on the page.
    itemtmp = null;
}
```

Comment: @PriyaViji could you outcomment it and try to run the code. Also the exact line that generates the error would be nice.

Comment: the error occurs in 1st replaceChild call -  parent.replaceChild(item2,item1)

Comment: @PriyaViji, As Jonathan said, we need more code. Supply your HTML as well as the references from the arrays you use.